# Root cannot append to file in /tmp

Tags: permissions, chmod, tmp

As root run:

```
cd /tmp
seq 10 > foo
chmod 666 foo
seq 10 >> foo
chown daemon foo
seq 10 >> foo
```

This gives:

```
-bash: foo: Permission denied
```

It is clear that it is due to `/tmp`'s special permission (drwxrwxrw**t**), because it works fine in `/tmp/bardir`.

But why? Should the group ownership and permission not allow `root` to append to the file?

```
$ ls -l foo
-rw-rw-rw- 1 daemon root 42 Dec  6 09:11 foo
$ lsattr foo
-------------------- foo
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 34 root root 137 Dec  6 09:11 /tmp
$ lsattr -d /tmp
-------------------- /tmp
```

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: @NasirRiley Not that I know of. It is a normal Ubuntu 20.04, and I have not actively installed SELinux.

Comment: The behavior has been changed in Ubuntu 20.04. The same doesn't occur in Debian 10 (Buster) or CentOS 8.2. To set it back to what it was in Ubuntu 18.04, use this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250974/user-root-cant-write-to-file-in-tmp-owned-by-someone-else-in-20-04-but-can-in